# Having trouble seeing an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arraylist

I was converting over a method that written for arrays to be used to find the mode for an ArrayList passed from main. Somewhere along the way I'm hitting and index error. Im sure its an obvious mistake, but just not seeing it. Would love another set of eyes on this!

```
 public static int getMode(ArrayList<Integer> a)
 {
  int i ,j ,ctr=0 ,wantedScore ,maxsofar ,position=0 ,mode;
    ArrayList<Integer> ctrArray = new ArrayList<>(a.size());
    for(i=0; 1< a.size(); i++)
    {
        wantedScore = a.get(i);
        for(j=i+1; j < a.size(); j++)
        {
            if(a.get(i)==wantedScore)
            {
                ctr++;

            }//End IF 
        ctrArray.add(ctr);

        }//End Inner Loop
    }//End Outer For Loop
    //Find highest value counter
    maxsofar=a.get(0);
    for(i=0; i< a.size(); i++)
    {
        if(ctrArray.get(i)>maxsofar)
        {
            maxsofar=ctrArray.get(i);
            position=i;
        }//End If
    }//End For Loop
    if(maxsofar>0)
        mode=a.get(position);
    else
        mode=-1;

    return mode;
}//End getMode
```

The error I'm getting if the Array list contains the values 1, 2, 3 is: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3

Comment: Why don't you use for-each:
`for(int i : a) { ...`

Answer (score 5):

```
 for(i=0; 1< a.size(); i++)
```

it should be   `for(i=0; i< a.size(); i++)`

Comment: wow. okay I cant believe I didn't see that! Thank you so much for the help! I'm taking this as a sign that I should get some sleep haha